# cUnit tests running on hudson

Tags: c, unit-testing, hudson, cunit

i'm looking for some plugin in hudson that runs unit tests, i get two names post build task, and CMake build, but by description anyone was created to run unit tests, them i want some indication about tools that help me to achieve this, or some tutorial or link that make one of these two tools work like expected to my case.

Answer (score 2):

Hudson (or preferably [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), which is much more actively maintained and improved) doesn't have plugins to run unit tests per se - you would normally do that as a step in your build script.  I think the Cmake build would handle it in your case, e.g. "cmake test"

You'd need to look at a unit test framework that works with the language your code is written in - JUnit or TestNFG for Java, CPPUnit for C/C++, NUnit for .NET, etc.

Hudson / Jenkins do have plugins that will record the unit test results - the [xUNit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) is a good generic example.